# Why does shuffling in train test split have a big impact with my loss and accuracy?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, validation, train

I used Keras for the train test split.

This is what I get when I shuffle during my train test split:

[image]

When I disable shuffle by setting `shuffle:False` this is what I get:

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that data in your training set is not ordered randomly, or at least, there's some unlucky order of the data. Seems like when training on unshuffled data, given the initial samples, your model finds some unfavorable local minima and it is hard for it to unlearn it when looking at the latter samples.

The solution in many cases would be just to randomly shuffle the data. It may also be a good idea to do in-depth exploratory analysis of your data, to check what exactly could be the issue with ordering. You could split your data by indexes into some number of bins and then compare the bins between each other looking at different plots and summary statistics (depending on what exactly your data is). You could also check if there is a correlation between index and some variables, or if adding index as a feature to your model plays a significant role in it (usually you would need more interpretable model for this, e.g. logistic regression). Maybe there some other issues with the data that you were not aware of?

Comment: generally in this cases you *should not* shuffle your data, because the new data for which you want your model to work well on will present the same issue, and you want your model to be robust to it (even provident, at best)

Comment: @carlo which "this case"? Given the description, we know nothing about the nature of the data, so I can't see how you could make such strong statements.

Comment: intrinsically ordered data

Comment: @carlo nobody said that this data is intrinsically ordered. It could simply be the case that, e.g. those are images and first half of the data consist only of the black-and-white images, while second of colour images, because this is how they where collected.

Comment: you are right. anyway, there is a solid possibility that shuffling the data is the wrong thing to do

Comment: @carlo that why in the last paragraph I wrote single sentence on shuffling and multiple comments on finding the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Tim My data is similar to EEG signals where I have 3331x7x26 where 7 is # of Samples and 26 is # of Channels.

Comment: @Calebjones so I'd split your training set into $k$ bins and then sample few signals and look at the EEG plots: are there any visible differences between different parts of the data? Maybe the signals were samples using different EEG machines, or by different lab technicians, or the study subjects differ somehow? You should check stuff like this first.

Comment: @Tim Unfortunately I can't use a different machine to collect data, have to work with what I have.

Comment: @Tim This is one approach to train test split if I'm not using Keras's train test split function. 
This function doesn't shuffle:
`def train_test_split_sequential(X, Y, **options):
    test_size = options.pop('test_size', None)
    if test_size is None:
        test_size = 0.25
        
    n_sample = len(Y)
    n_test = int(n_sample * test_size)
        
    X_train = X[:-n_test]
    Y_train = Y[:-n_test]
    Y_train = np.squeeze(Y_train)

    X_test = X[-n_test:]
    Y_test = Y[-n_test:]
    Y_test = np.squeeze(Y_test)
    return X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test   `

Comment: Are the EEG samples = different patients?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Nope multiples run for the same subject. These are fNIRS signals btw not EEG.

Comment: @Calebjones Hi to fellow vibrational spectroscopist! Are you analyzing the data unfolded to (3331*7) x 26 channels, i.e. channels are your features/variates? and 3331 is the time axis?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX
3331 is the time axis 
7 is # of samples
26 is Channels 13 for HbO and 13 for HbR(oxy deoxy hemoglobin)

Comment: I'm wondering how exactly the data is handled in keras (I haven't worked with keras so far, I mostly use bilinear models on spectra with far more channels). Specifically, are the dimensions in the right order for keras? So along which of your 3 dimensions is the train/test split (the one done by keras)? On a higher level: if you have 7 samples/repeated runs for the same subject I expect that you *should* shuffle & split by sample (there may be situations where this is not necessary, though - but we can determine that only from a detailed description of what the model should predict).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109231/discussion-between-caleb-jones-and-cbeleites-unhappy-with-sx).